# Creative stdin and error handling for python

Tags: python, stdout, stdin

I use a third-party program on Windows10 -- call it SuckySoftware.exe.

This program can launch a python script and do other stuff.

When it launches a python script, unfortunately I don't get a command window launched. This creates three problems:

1) I can't give it input. For example using python3 and having "input()" as one of the commands causes SuckySoftware.exe to hang, because it is waiting for input into some non-existent command window.

2) I can't get output. So "print('hello')" doesn't show up anywhere

3) There is no error handling. So if I have a ValueError in my python code, it silently fails on that line and doesn't execute the rest of the python.

I've solved #2 by doing:

```
sys.stdout = open(logfile, 'wb', 0)
sys.stdout.write('hello'.encode('utf-8'))
```

and then using mTail to monitor logfile in real-time.

I can't figure out how to solve 1 or 3.

For 1, I wonder if there is a simple way of launching a simple GUI with one textbox. Whenever my logfile shows "Please enter a value" then I could enter it in to that textbox and press enter, and it would take it on stdin. However this seems overly complicated.

For 3, I wonder if I can catch all error messages (including the line number it failed on) and print them to stdout before the script quits.

Ideas?

Comment: Does opening a file as `sys.stderr` not address #3?

Comment: Nope! Unless I'm doing it wrong. I do: sys.stderr = open(logfile,'wb',0);raise ValueError('blah'). Nothing is put in the logfile. Same thing if I do an intentional syntax error like print(,,,,). I know writing to the logfile is working because I can do sys.stderr.write('blah'.encode('utf-8')) and that works.

Comment: It does however cease the script on: raise ValueError('blah'). In other words if I put a .write statement before and after that, the one before executes but the one after does not. So the error is raised and execution halts, but the actual error isn't written to logfile.

Answer (score 0):

First, do open a file as `sys.stderr`, since output there may be useful in any event.

1. The simplest, most portable technique is to set `sys.stdin` to a (TCP, aka `SOCK_STREAM`) socket connection to another process.
2. You can use such a socket as `sys.stdout` and/or `sys.stderr` as well, although then the helper process has to use `select` to handle the multiple streams without deadlock.  (You might want to use a *wrapper* as `sys.stderr` to preserve its unbuffered status.)
3. Assign a function to `sys.excepthook` that reports the exception via (your) `stderr`.  (There is perhaps something already assigning such a function, since nothing shows up on `sys.stderr` as it is.)